# When refactoring code into separate files, "TS2345: Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type"

Tags: typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm refactoring my React app. I got the following error.

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ standardHeaders: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInit'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'standardHeaders' does not exist in type 'RequestInit'.
```

This is my original code, which works without any TypeScript errors:

```
  const headers = new Headers({
    Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json',
  });
  fetch(url, { headers })
```

Then I moved headers to a separate file because it is used in several places:

**globals.tsx**

```
export const standardHeaders = new Headers({
  Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json',
});
```

**myfile.tsx**

```
import { standardHeaders } from '../globals';
fetch(url, { standardHeaders })
```

This causes the "type is not assignable to parameter" error.

I assume I need to set the type of `standardHeaders` somehow, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valid 2nd parameter of `fetch` is an object containing `headers` instead of `standardHeaders` so as long as you change the property then it would work:

```js
import { standardHeaders } from '../globals';
fetch(url, { headers: standardHeaders })
```

Your original code has variable name and property are the same `headers` that's why it works normally